# Moq: How to ensure Verify() reports on non-matching parameters

Tags: moq

I have the following unit test verification using Moq:

```
var mock = new Mock<IDoSomethingUseful>();

var sut = new Thingy(mock.Object);
sut.CallDoSomethingUseful();

mock.Verify(
    somethingUseful => somethingUseful.Move(
        It.Is<MyVector>( 
            myVector => myVector.x == 123)), Times.Once, "This fail message needs to be hard-coded with myVector.x was not equal to 123");
```

- How can I get Verify() to tell me that the predicate match failed? The test runner only reports that the call failed so I need to rely on the hard-coded message.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Callback` the invocation arguments can be accessed. See section *Callbacks*  [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

---

In your case you could add an *expected* value for `x` to the test and get the *actual* value in Callback. Finally use an [Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243496.aspx) to verify if expected and actual values equal where the message can be formated using both values. HTH

```
int expected_x_value = 123;
int actual_x_value = 0;

var mock = new Mock<IDoSomethingUseful>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Move(It.IsAny<MyVector>()))
    .Callback<MyVector>(
        (v) => 
        {
            actual_x_value = v.x;
        }
    );

var sut = new Thingy(mock.Object);
sut.CallDoSomethingUseful();

Assert.AreEqual(expected_x_value, actual_x_value, 
    string.Format("myVector.x was expected to be called with x = '{0}' but was '{1}'", 
                   expected_x_value, actual_x_value));
```

Comment: Thanks Dee, I will try this out.